# How to determine the order of SARIMA Model?

Tags: forecasting, arima, seasonality

[image]

[image]

I am trying to forecast hourly wind speeds for a couple of years. My dataset contained trends and seasonality so a applied a difference of 24 to remove seasonality and then another difference to remove trends. This is the resulting autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation function. I would like to know how to determine the order of the SARIMA model= (p,d,q)*(P,D,Q)[s]?

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion would be to feed your series into R as a `ts` object and then let `auto.arima()` from [the `forecast` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) select an appropriate seasonality. This is an established piece of software that will almost certainly do a better job than if you applied something you read about here. (If you do want to "roll your own", you can read up on [the OCSB test for seasonality that `auto.arima()` uses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30225/1352).

However, and more importantly, you may have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), since wind speeds may not only show day-over-day patterns, but also year-over-year ones, so you have cycles of length both $24$ and $365.25\times 24=8766$. Multiple seasonalities can be modeled and forecasted using the `bats()` and `tbats()` function in the `forecast` package. See also [the multiple-seasonalities tag info](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info).

Comment: My dataset only consists of a year & a half hourly wind speeds, would that mean that there is a monthly seasonality?

Comment: There is probably no intra-month seasonality, since months are human constructs and not tied into natural cycles, in contrast to years, where there is the summer-winter cycle. I don't know how `bats/tbats` deals with having seen less than two full outer cycles. Try it!